# How to operate a remote laptop?

Tags: vnc, remote-access

I need to support a person's remote Ubuntu laptop, from my Ubuntu desktop. I need the ability to use my desktop to access the remote laptop and take control of the laptop: install apps; invoke apps; browse the net; transfer files to and fro; etc. I need to see the remote laptop monitor on my desktop monitor.

What needs to be installed on laptop and desktop; how to configure; what protocol to use: how to establish the connection between the two machines?

Comment: Is the laptop on the same LAN as you? Or is it remote as in on a fully different LAN?

Comment: The desktop and remote are situated in different cities. So the connection will be via the public internet.

Comment: Remote operation is easy and well-documented: Your basic choices are SSH, VNC, RDP, X2GO. Do a bit of research and pick the one you understand best. Most folks get tripped up on the networking bit -- how to access that remote laptop if it's on the wrong side of a router in that different city. That's a totally different question unrelated to the protocol, and your options will depend on what kind of help you have at the other end to initiate an SSH tunnel, and what kind of infrastructure is on your end.

Comment: uh, if remote is so easy and documented, I would not be asking on this forum. I need step-by-step instructions for both ends. Thanks.

Comment: It is very easy and very documented. People will be keen to help if you ask questions that indicate you've made a bit of an effort. You've been around here long enough to get that, surely? If you just want jump straight to the best solution, use nomachine desktop.

Comment: I am using "AnyDesk" to support people behind a router/firewall. Since that is purely private I don't mind using an intermediate server.

Comment: to all... I shall try your suggestions. appreciated. thanks for replies.